# Uniquely identifiable item vs. nonunique identifiable item

Tags: nouns, synonyms

*Edit: The question itself is not about naming variables, but about finding two words that properly differentiate between two meanings.*

I am in the process of building a system that stores entities in a database. But I am having a hard time coming up with the proper nouns for two entities.

One entity is uniquely identifiable by a serial number. For example a laptop.
The other entity is not uniquely identifiable. For example a mouse or keyboard (I know they usually are identifiably, but that is not required in this system).

How would you name each entity? I was thinking about **Item/Miscellaneous Item** but that just feels weird and wrong. I have also thought about **Product/Item** as that differentiates a bit more.

Comment: What is `Fx`? _Fx a laptop_ and _Fx a mouse or keyboard_

Comment: @marcellothearcane I'm guessing it means "For example". I'm not sure that the question is really on-topic here, since programming variable naming is not limited to English language rules (or even English language words).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about English language as defined by the [help], it's about naming programming variables.

Comment: I know that the question is regarding naming programming variables, but I prefer to name according to the English language, and thus I was looking for an English word. Not a programming variable name. I just added the context for added info.

Comment: But MiscItem is not standard English. / You have not added reasonable research (synonyms of item / product) and why they don't work. //// You'll probably not get better than 'uniquely identifiable' and 'non-uniquely-identifiable', admittedly unwieldy classifiers. 'Specific' (in the required/related usage, usually of old medicines) and 'generic' are rare as nouns.

Comment: You are right, I didn't add all the synonyms I looked at and why they didn't work. I will do better next time I ask a question. And I'm sorry the context was misleading. I was just looking for two single words that would properly differentiate between the two meanings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Generic** item* ge·ner·ic  (jə-nĕr′ĭk) adj.

1.a. Relating to or descriptive of an entire group or class: Cancer is a generic term for a group of diseases in which cells proliferate wildly.

b. Lacking specificity; general: made some generic remarks about how to save for retirement.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/generic

Comment: That is a possibility. Hadn't thought of that. Would prefer a single word if that's possible, but generic is very descriptive.

Comment: @Neophear generic _is_ a single word.

Comment: @Greybeard My bad. I thought about is as an adjective. But you are right in that it can be used as a noun.